# Cannot run XCUITest - Image not found error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to start writing UI tests with Xcode, but getting "Image not found" error.

I tried cleaning, deleting Derived Data folder, restarting Xcode, none of them work. I see people fixing this by adding the framework manually, but I install frameworks using cocoa pod and can't find the .framework package to add it (Yep, I have no idea how cocoa pod works, magic I guess). In the pod file I have `use_framworks!`.
The unit test target have the same pod settings and can run just fine. Test recording works as well.

Here is the log when run the test:

```
2019-06-11 08:30:25.856179-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
2019-06-11 08:30:25.856303-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] [AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen orientation
2019-06-11 08:30:25.893543-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
2019-06-11 08:30:25.897466-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] [AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
2019-06-11 08:30:25.897583-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] [AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen orientation
2019-06-11 08:30:26.003946-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] Running tests...
2019-06-11 08:30:26.445155-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] The bundle “MyAppUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2019-06-11 08:30:26.445347-0500 MyAppUITests-Runner[22921:238461] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gwxcidgxbavmezgiqxonawmgsinw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/MyAppUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAccelerate.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gwxcidgxbavmezgiqxonawmgsinw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/Frameworks/Kingfisher.framework/Kingfisher
  Reason: image not found)
```

Comment: did you configure UI Test target in your podfile?

Comment: yes, it has the same settings as simulator target and unit test target

Comment: check this - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5250#issuecomment-424301165 . It may help you.

Comment: UITest target is not nested in the main app target, all the targets are separated

Comment: I fixed this once with a pod deintegrate & reinstall. However, no guarantee it will fix it in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys, but still no luck for me